# Add unique styling to one form in a Django formset

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a formset with four forms, and want to render the fourth one with different CSS from the others - unique color, styling, etc. Can I do this from my html page, or somewhere else?

I'm looking for something like this pseudo-code:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {{ formset.non_form_errors }}
    <div>
    {% for form in formset except the last form %}
        {% for field in form %}
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for the last form in the formset %}
        {% for field in form %}
            {{ field.errors }}
            <div class="different style">
                {{ field.label_tag }}: 
                <p class="another different style">{{ field }}</p>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `forloop.last` in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#for) -

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {{ formset.non_form_errors }}
    <div>
    {% for form in formset %}
        {% if forloop.last %}
            {% for field in form %}
                {{ field.errors }}
                <div class="different style">
                    {{ field.label_tag }}: 
                    <p class="another different style">{{ field }}</p>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            {% for field in form %}
                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! You have an extra `{% endfor %}` and need `}` after {% endif %`.